# telegram.bot in R Error in curl::curl-fetch-memory(url, handle = handle) : Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: r, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I have been running the telegram bot function below for over a year.

[image]

But now, I'm getting error this message:

[image]

I'm not sure why I suddenly got this error message with nothing changed in my script. Your input is greatly appreciated!